# Изменение определённого объекта в списке в Python

Tags: python, строки, типы-данных, int

Хочу узнать,как менять определённый тип объектов в списке,если список состоит из неопределённого количества разных объектов разных типов данных:
Например,нужно,чтобы это:

```
>    Input:
>    Олег заработал сегодня 3000 рублЯ
>    Маша заработала сегодня 3123 рублЯ
>    Витя заработал сегодня 3441 рублЬ
```

Превратилось в это (здесь сумма увеличится,допустим,на 20 процентов):

```
>    Output:
>    Олег заработал сегодня 3600 рублЕЙ
>    Маша заработала сегодня 3747 рублЕЙ и 60 копеек
>    Витя заработал сегодня 3,129 рублЕЙ и 20 копеек
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите пример в виде код на Python.

Answer (score 2):

можно так:

```
value = 3712
words = ['рубль', 'рубля', 'рублей']

word = words[2 if 10 <= value % 100 <= 20 or value % 10 > 4 else 0 if value % 10 == 1 else 1]

print(f'{value} {word}')
```

если нужно обработать запрос вида
`[имя операция] [действие] [дата] [значение] [валюта]`,
то можно так:

```
def getForm(value, forms):
    return forms[2 if 10 <= value % 100 <= 20 or value % 10 > 4 else 0 if value % 10 == 1 else 1]

text = 'Олег заработал сегодня 3000 рублей'
coeff = 3.141592

elements = text.split()

value = float(elements[3]) * coeff    

rubles = int(value)
kopecks = int(100 * (value - rubles))

text = ' '.join([elements[0], elements[1], str(rubles), getForm(rubles, ['рубль', 'рубля', 'рублей'])] + ([] if kopecks == 0 else [str(kopecks), getForm(kopecks, ['копейка', 'копейки', 'копеек'])]))

print(text)
```

Comment: Нет,цена и текст - это просто пример. Мне неизвестно, что будет введено пользователем (сколько строк, какие буквы, что именно, будут ли там числа и т.п)

Comment: т.е. вам надо распарсить строку ввода и сформировать новую строку?

Comment: Да,нужно именно это

Comment: понял, посмотрите такой эффект нужен? (я в ответе добавил код)

Comment: Нет,нужно,чтобы человек вводил любой текст,в котором менялись только числа,текст состоит из неопределённого количества строк,которе мы не знаем (Спасибо большое за старания!)